# What does -D -a mean in the output of ps -p <pid> -o command?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I entered `ps -p 3454 -o command` and the output I got was:

```
COMMAND
/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh
```

What does `-D -a` mean here?

If I use `ps -p 3454 -o comm`, I am not getting the /run/user.... output, just the command `ssh-agent`.

What is the meaning of /run/user.... here? Also is `comm=` and `comm` same?

Comment: So `-D`  and `-a` flags are not related to the `command` argument of `ps` command. The SSH specific info is beyond my understanding so far. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer for you to help clarify further and removed my comment. I put some of the comment detail into the answer plus some other stuff that should clarify for you specifically.  You are welcome @Cruise5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ps(1) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) and per my testing, here's some detail to help clarify this output. This will help you better understand what's going on with the `ps` command you are running.

Your entire command is this `ps -p 3454 -o command`

- The `ps -p 3454` part of this gets the active running process detail for pid `3454`
- The `-o command` part of this outputs the actual command and arguments of the running process tied to the pid

When you ran this to show pid `3453` detail, that happened to be the [ssh-agent](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-agent.1.html) process. Using the `-o command` outputs the raw command and arguments for `ssh-agent` which were using `-D -a` parameters at the time the `ps` command took the snapshot.

Using just `-o comm` actually just outputs that pid's executing file name only. This really just means `-o comm` and `-o command` display different detail of the process you are querying.

---

## Supporting Resources

- [ps(1) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)

  > - `comm`:
  >
  >   - Show command name (only the executable name). Modifications to the command name will not be shown. The output in this column may
  >     contain spaces.
  > - `command`:
  >
  >   - Show command with all its arguments as a string. Modifications to the arguments may be shown. The output in this column may contain
  >     spaces.

Answer (score 1):

the "-D -a" have nothing to do with PS.  PS is listing the processes - and a running process is "/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh" - ie the -D -a are parameters passed to ssh-agent.

With respect to ssh-agent: -D means run in foreground, and -a means "bind to all addresses".

On my Ubuntu system, I see 2 "ssh-agent" processes - one in the background, presumably related to command line stuff I'm doing, while a second one is a client of the desktop session, so likely in the foreground so it can interact with that.  (Indeed when I kill the process associated with the one with the -D -a options and do an ssh session from the desktop it asks me to authenticate again, and relaunches that process)